# "Loading available Gradle versions has encountered a problem" in workspace-spring-tool-suite

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-tool-suite

[**STS Error**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXWXj.jpg)

I was trying to install STS and this is the error that I'm facing on opening any existing project. I already have JDK installed on my system along with Eclipse IDE. What can I do to solve this? Any help would be appreciated.

[**List of Errors**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pf3y1.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I guess that this is related to the version of the JDK that you use to run the IDE (it is probably using the JRE that ships as part of the distribution, whether it is Eclipse or Spring Tools directly) vs. the version of the JDK that the Gradle version of your project is compatible with.

The easiest way to solve this (in case that is the problem) is to update the Gradle version of your project config to the latest one. The other option is to use a different JDK to run the IDE, but keep in mind that Eclipse and Spring Tools both require at least a JDK 11 - and from September onwards a JDK 17. So the best way would be to upgrade the project to use a more recent Gradle version.

If this guesswork here is wrong, please update the problem description with a full stack trace - which you can get from the Error Log View - to reveal more details, describe the Gradle and JDK versions being used here, to allow a more precise guesswork... :-)